# can't send mail using mail_form gem on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mail-form

I have a rails app where I need a contact form.
I am using mail_form gem and I can send mail from the rails console but not from the form..
Followed several videos and tutorials, but none seems to work on this issue..

Controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contacts_params)
    @contact.request = request

    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message. We will contact you soon!'
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Cannot send message'
      render :new
    end
  end

  protected

  def contacts_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
  end
end
```

the contact.rb

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :file,      :attachment => true

  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "My Contact Form",
      :to => "tcunha_lp@hotmail.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

server log displays:

```
Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-19 11:40:45 +0000
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yLolqR/aOQ1T75HJr4f+DlGwbw6e67FwVoLuWNr/MIs2PdFbdx/626SUqTjw0xbb+9xmy4zg2mzZKYt9XXYNdA==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>"", "message"=>""}, "commit"=>"Send"}
 Rendering contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
 Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
 Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (0.7ms)
 Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (53.4ms)
 Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (0.2ms)
 Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (51.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 767ms (Views: 761.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

the env config should be OK, since I can send mail from the console..

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I get no error.. Interesting thing.. Just started the computer, tried to send the email and it worked!! Went for it the second time and it is not working again...?

Comment: That only time that worked, it renders a contact.erb file from mail_form folder... For some reason, rails is skipping this